# Always be asking for a user input while tkinter window is open

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am creating a program and I need to make it so while the tkinter GUI is open, the user can still type something in the console. So while a window is open, the user can input a command.

How would I go around doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: you can't, the program is frozen inside tk's mainloop

Comment: To which console do you refer?

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other multithreaded program, start the worker (tkinter GUI in this case) in a new thread. Here's an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import threading

class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        lbl=tk.Label(self, text='Tkinter program')
        lbl.pack()

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        win = GUI(root)
        win.pack()
        root.mainloop()

w = Worker()
w.start()
```

Comment: How does this allow the user to still type something into the console?

Comment: @martineau Assuming it was launched from the REPL (I assume that's what OP means with 'console') or in interactive mode (`-i` flag) this will start the GUI and drop back to the REPL prompt.

Comment: I do believe tkinter is not a thread safe library. Would this affect the behavior of tkinter?

Comment: @DarthCadeus When a module is not thread safe that means you should not use more than one thread with that module. As long as all the tkinter calls are in the same thread you are fine. That said, tkinter really should be in the main thread if possible.